# Approximate indicator of sphere with derivative of test function

Tags: real-analysis, integration, harmonic-functions

Suppose I know that
$$
\int_{\Omega} \varphi |Dv|^2 = \int_{\Omega} v\; Dv\cdot D\varphi
$$
holds for every $\varphi \in C^1_c(\Omega)$ (this is an easy identity for harmonic functions but that is more or less beside the point of my question).

Can I let $\varphi$ approximate the characteristic function of a ball i.e.
$$
\varphi \to \mathbf{1}_{B_{\rho}(x_0)}
$$
in order to deduce *directly* something like 
$$
\int_{B_{\rho}(x_0)}|Dv|^2 = \int_{\partial B_{\rho}(x_0)} v\; Dv\cdot \frac{(x-x_0)}{\rho}
$$
without doing another argument in between?

I feel like I've seen people do this, but you can't actually $W^{1,2}$ converge to $\mathbf{1}_{B_{\rho}(x_0)}$ or anything like that so in what sense does the second identity hold?

Comment: Does splitting off the radial integral and appealing to corresponding result in $\mathbb{R}$ count as "another argument in between"?

Comment: The usual arguments iirc go via DCT. But  $D\phi$ would indeed converge to a measure supported on $\partial B_\rho$ (related - https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2908322/80734). its OK for its integral to converge( in $\mathbb R$) without it itself converging as a function (c.f. Dirac delta)

Comment: @user10354138 no not really, but how would that go? What's the corresponding result in $\mathbb{R}$? Seems either way like Calvin Khor suggests you need a distributional interpretation somehow.?